# Generate or create OGC WMS using Python mapnik

Tags: python, postgis, wms, mapnik, ogcserver

I want to create an OGC WMS server from mapnik PostGIS using Python.

I have successfully post table on PostGIS using:

```
shp2pgsql -s 4326 /Users/apple/Downloads/111SHAPEFILE/Point.shp points | psql -d gis -U apple -h localhost
```

then I successfully connect mapnik with PostGIS database using:

```
from mapnik import PostGIS
postgis = PostGIS(dbname="gis", user = "apple", host = "localhost", port = '' ,password = "", table= 'points')
```

I want to create OGC WMS server from mapnik, how can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Try Mapproxy that does what you want https://mapproxy.org e.g serve Mapnik based project(s) as WMS

There is also this old project but unmaintained https://github.com/mapnik/OGCServer

In both cases, you need to write your Mapnik configuration to XML and use this XML as an input. This XML can be generated via Python by declaring your datasource, styles, etc and finish by using `save_map_to_string` method from mapnik like below sample (it uses both shapefile and PostGIS as data sources)

```py
import mapnik 

# Instantiate a map object with given width, height and spatial reference 
# system 
m = mapnik.Map(600,300,"+proj=latlong +datum=WGS84") 
# Set background colour to 'steelblue'. 
# You can use 'named' colours, #rrggbb, #rgb or rgb(r%,g%,b%) format 
m.background = mapnik.Color('steelblue') 
                                                                                                                                    

s = mapnik.Style() 
# A Style can have one or more rules. A rule consists of a filter, min/max 
# scale demoninators and 1..N Symbolizers. If you don't specify filter and 
# scale denominators you get default values : 
#   Filter =  'ALL' filter (meaning symbolizer(s) will be applied to all 
#   features) 
#   MinScaleDenominator = 0 
#   MaxScaleDenominator = INF 
# Lets keep things simple and use default value, but to create a map we 
# we still must provide at least one Symbolizer. Here we  want to fill 
# countries polygons with greyish colour and draw outlines with a bit 
# darker stroke. 
r=mapnik.Rule()
polySym = mapnik.PolygonSymbolizer() 
polySym.fill = mapnik.Color('#f2eff9') 
r.symbols.append(polySym) 
lineSymb = mapnik.LineSymbolizer() 
lineSymb.stroke = mapnik.Color('rgb(50%,50%,50%)') 
r.symbols.append(lineSymb) 
s.rules.append(r)

# Here we have to add our style to the Map, giving it a name.
m.append_style('My Style',s)

# Here we instantiate our data layer, first by giving it a name and srs
# (proj4 projections string), and then by giving it a datasource.
lyr = mapnik.Layer('world',"+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs")
# Then provide the full filesystem path to a shapefile in WGS84 or
# EPSG 4326 projection without the .shp extension
# A sample shapefile can be downloaded from
# https://www.naturalearthdata.com/http//www.naturalearthdata.com/download/110m/cultural/ne_110m_admin_0_countries.zip
lyr.datasource = mapnik.Shapefile(file='/home/thomasg/Téléchargements/ne_10m/ne_10m_admin_0_countries')

lyr1 = mapnik.Layer('populated_places',"+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs")
lyr1.datasource = mapnik.PostGIS(dbname="states",
    user="osm", host="localhost",
    password = "osm", table= 'ne_110m_populated_places')


s1 = mapnik.Style()
r1 = mapnik.Rule()
markerSym = mapnik.MarkersSymbolizer()
markerSym.fill = mapnik.Color("darkorange")
markerSym.stroke= mapnik.Color("orange")
r1.symbols.append(markerSym)
s1.rules.append(r1)
m.append_style('Style Points',s1)

lyr1.styles.append('Style Points')

lyr.styles.append('My Style')

m.layers.append(lyr)
m.layers.append(lyr1)

m.zoom_to_box(lyr1.envelope())

# Write the data to a png image called world.png in the base directory of your user to see infos
mapnik.render_to_file(m,'world.png', 'png')

# print(mapnik.save_map_to_string(m))

with open('my_mapnik.xml', 'w') as infile:
    infile.write(mapnik.save_map_to_string(m))
# Exit the python interpreter
exit()
```

You can also generated manually or using CartoCSS editor and generate your XML from the CartoCSS styles.

Comment: I get some issues on import ogcserver into python using: 
**import ogcserver**, **from mapnik.ogcserver.WMS import BaseWMSFactory**  wi you please help me to solve this issue, i want to create **OGC server** using postgis data into mapnik in python.

Comment: OGCServer unmaintained. You are on your own. As I wrote, you can generate from your Python an XML file that contain references to your PostGIS database and use this file to run an OGC Server. OGCServer and Mapproxy are both OGC servers able to serve WMS.

Comment: thanks for the code you provide. Do you have any example of **mapnik with mapproxy** in python, like how we can implement the generated xml input into mapproxy in python.

Comment: Not aware, because mapproxy is not a library. It's intended to run standalone. It seems you are thinking that everything should be called from Python whereas it's not the way it works, at least for default mapproxy behaviour. You may set Mapproxy configuration (YAML files) from Python but you will run it using standalone commands mentioned in their doc. Look at section https://mapproxy.org/docs/nightly/sources.html#mapnik-label to configure source (your XML) and section https://mapproxy.org/docs/nightly/services.html#wms-service-label for service WMS config.

Comment: Can't help more: there are no Python example to my knowledge as it has never intended to work this way. A WMS server and other web servers in general In Python are always using a wsgi app or fastcgi as point of entry to run them standalone. It's exactly what mapproxy does